# Anchoring view components programmatically gives error

Tags: swift

I have 2 buttons on the screen, the lower one is anchored to the view's bottom anchor, and the one above that is anchored to the lower button's top anchor. However, this throws an error "'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

I have already added both buttons to the view (view.addSubView) and set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, no help.

```
view.addSubview(topButton)
topButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:         view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
topButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
topButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 180).isActive = true
topButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  lowerButton.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true

view.addSubview(lowerButton)
lowerButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
lowerButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
lowerButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 220).isActive = true
lowerButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: -50).isActive = true
```

What I want for to happen is the lower button anchored to the view's bottom anchor, and the top button's bottom anchor anchored to the lower button's top anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding constraints involving lowerButton before you actually add it to the view hierarchy. Simply move `view.addSubview(lowerButton)` to right below adding the topButton.